# why we need tf.convert_to_tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I saw the following code in(https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager):

```
def fizzbuzz(max_num):
  counter = tf.constant(0)
  max_num = tf.convert_to_tensor(max_num)
  for num in range(1, max_num.numpy()+1):
    num = tf.constant(num)
    if int(num % 3) == 0 and int(num % 5) == 0:
      print('FizzBuzz')
    elif int(num % 3) == 0:
      print('Fizz')
    elif int(num % 5) == 0:
      print('Buzz')
    else:
      print(num.numpy())
    counter += 1


fizzbuzz(15)
```

why does max_num need to convert tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, it only serves a simple demonstrative purpose (i.e. showing how Eager works) - otherwise, it's redundant. If the question is "why use tensors is Eager?" - 
TensorFlow ops can only operate on tensor instances (e.g. `Tensor`, `EagerTensor`) - even in Eager execution. Eager isn't actually devoid of graph - it's *mostly* graph, 'executed graph'.

As for 'why' - long question, but short answer is "optimization"; before actually executing, TensorFlow intelligently organizes and type-casts inputs - and doing so requires inputs to have certain attributes and methods, which are inherited once they are cast to tensors. When using high-level ops, this is done automatically, but if writing custom functionality (e.g. optimizers), you may need to convert manually.